# Using d3.js to create a dynamic scatter graph based on imported JSON file

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm trying to use D3JS to visualize data from different JSON files. The goal is to be able to import any JSON file that will be generated from a relational database and a scatter graph should be created using the data from the JSON.

I was reading through this page: http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6904504

I think I understand what's going on but this is all hard coded for that specific JSON file. I'm mainly just wondering if there's a suitable way to do what I want to achieve and where would I start looking to try and do this myself.

The main problem I'm having is that sometimes an axis is supposed to have numbers on it and other times it could have strings and this is were I'm having trouble figuring out right now.

I've been looking into using ordinal scales for the strings but the main problem I'm having there is can you use ordinal scale on numbers but still have be linear?

Comment: A scatter plot has *quantitative* variables in both axes. If you're dealing with categorical (qualitative) variables, you can't create a scatter plot.

Comment: My goal is to check whether I'm comparing two numbers or a string and a number and change the type of visualisation you get dynamically if that's even possible. So a scatter graph or a bar chart etc. depending on the data types.